# undefined method 'env' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

This is what my spec file looks like: `spec/api/v1/projects_spec.rb`

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "/api/v1/projects", :type => :api do
  context "projects viewable by this user" do
   it "JSON" do
   end
  end
end
```

It contained a lot more but I deleted a lot of lines in an unsuccessful attempt to find the error which goes like this:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

This piece of code is from the "Rails 3 in Action" by Ryan Bigg. The only other file it includes is: `spec/support/api/helper.rb`

```
module ApiHelper
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
   Rails.application
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include ApiHelper, :type => :api
end
```

I've been trying to google the error for the past 1 hr and the closest thing that I found was [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1114) and as a result I deleted the code which used Devise::Test_Helpers. Sadly, its still not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

### Stack Trace

```
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:24:in `setup_controller_for_warden'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-rails-2.8.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:35:in `instance_eval'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:35:in `run_in'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:70:in `block in run_all'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:70:in `each'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:70:in `run_all'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:368:in `run_hook'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:292:in `block in run_before_each_hooks'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:292:in `each'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:292:in `run_before_each_hooks'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:217:in `run_before_each'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:79:in `block in run'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:173:in `with_around_hooks'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:77:in `run'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:355:in `block in run_examples'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:351:in `map'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:351:in `run_examples'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:337:in `run'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:338:in `block in run'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:338:in `map'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:338:in `run'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
 # /home/prakhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: Adding more of the stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: BTW if you ***want*** to use Devise with Capybara, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284657/undefined-method-env-for-nilnilclass-in-setup-controller-for-warden-error/34738884#34738884)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're still including Devise::TestHelpers somewhere. Check and see what "spec_helper" is loading.

Comment: Yes. Spec_Helper is calling Devise::TestHelpers. How am I supposed to work around this in writing my tests?

Comment: Just `include Devise::TestHelpers` in the specs that use them. You don't have to globally include them for all specs. For example, leave `spec_helper.rb` alone, and in a test file `some_controller_spec.rb` be sure to call `include Devise::TestHelpers`

Comment: You also need to do some other setup, so to keep tests DRY, I made a Devise-specific subclass of ActionController::TestCase https://gist.github.com/mahemoff/8651382

Answer (score 4):

Instead of just including the Devise Test Helper, you can specify it's type, so that it's not included in routing spec:

```
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :helper
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```