# NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to testing my controller `posts` and when I running `Rspec` test, shell show me an error

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
 # /home/weare138/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:24:in `setup_controller_for_warden'
```

this is my `spec/requests/posts_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Posts" do
  describe "GET /posts" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, role: 'admin')
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

**UPD**

rails_helper

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :request
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

how fix?

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is quite old, but here's the solution for **request specs**. Try using:

`config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request`

instead of

`config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :request`

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with Devise::TestHlepers, as it can be seen from stacktrace.

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284657/undefined-method-env-for-nilnilclass-in-setup-controller-for-warden-error) (also check related questions too).

Comment: thank you, I find this question, but I didn't understand with this desicion

Comment: Are you added those helpers in your test env, like it's specified at readme https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers ?

Comment: Have you tried to specify test type in your test file like `describe "Posts", :type => :request do`