# Rails Devise Mailer undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm having issues now that i've added devise to my web app, theres a few SO questions on this but they just all point to a readme file and don't actually provide any fixes. I've had to include devise helpers as shown below in order to remove an issue saying the authentication method didn't exist

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
 fixtures :all

      # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

If i don't include it i end up with a huge amount of authentication errors:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
```

but if it is included

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

Simply occurs in different places instead, is there an actual fix?

Example

```
ContactMailerTest#test_should_return_contact_email:
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

Method:

```
test "should return contact email" do
mail = ContactMailer.contact_email("Email@Email.com", "Example",
                                   "SomeExample", @comment = "Hello")
assert_equal ['info@mynotes.com'], mail.to
assert_equal ['info@mynotes.com'], mail.from
end
```

This appears to be an issue with "Apparently there are issues with Devise::TestHelpers and integration testing" i am wondering if there is any known fix

Thanks!

Comment: I've simply got 3 models, one of which is a devise user model, and tests such as checking the GET commands work on web pages, the GET tests will fail as a result of including devise in the bundle

Comment: Show the code, the error is certainly in your code.

Comment: check you have test environment setup in your application database or not? also where you are getting  NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass??

Comment: not sure but looking duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284657/undefined-method-env-for-nilnilclass-in-setup-controller-for-warden-error

Comment: I've stated about that other SO articles don't answer the question, The tests have always worked before i added the devise gem, its only the mailer and the audits model playing up, the others seem to function fine

Comment: @kxdan show us where you have define mailer for test environment?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question @Arv